# Selenium doesn't work with long timeout

Tags: c#, selenium

I wrote code in C# use Selenium which tests functional. The goal is to put some text in a field, press a button and wait until the site after few times show additional forms. But my code works very strangely. If time very short: it works perfectly. But if the time is more than 30 sec, it throws exception. Here is part of my code, which wait when page loaded by Ajax data and show in the page:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        IWebElement myDynamicElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("smapxml"));
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        if (myDynamicElement != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ok. Element not null. Follow next step.");
            break;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error."+error.ToString());
        return;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"smapxml"}
   in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1092
```

So how do I fix this?

Comment: So the page takes 30 seconds to load? You've got two options, make your test wait *at least* 30 seconds or *fix the application*.

Comment: It's not my application, and I test product which work with this site. I have set the value of 2 minutes. After this time element "smapxml" is exist. I checked. But code generate exception. And I don't know why.

Comment: Is your code above what you use following your button click? So you're waiting for the new element(s)?